# Capture and analyse traffic

Tags: parsing, session, tcp, web-traffic

There are several websites that have important data for me, but have no API functions to retrieve this data. And I want to get this information and moreover I want to create my own API.

The first problem is that these websites store data behind their login pages so that I have to enter there, before I will be able to retrieve this data.

It should be mentioned that websites use JS to retrieve data and send queries back and also there is SSL protocol, so all traffic is encrypted.

My idea is

1. Capture traffic with Wireshark.
2. Decipher it.
3. Closely look though packages.
4. Here is the problem. Is there any tool that can reconstruct TCP session?

And finally. Can I create some sort of API that forges TCP session and the web server will identify this session as a session with a real browser or it is impossible? I've read about selenium, but it requires too much system's resources.

Comment: wireshark has "follow TCP stream" option, it will help you trace on a specific session. (right-click on a frame and you will have it in the context menu)

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to read the data from the browser developer tools. They allow you to see full request data and responses.

Then, to simulate a browser, you just need to send a similar request, with the same cookies and user agent, and there will be no difference from a real browser.

In modern browsers (such as Firefox or Chrome), you can go to Network tab on the developer tools and export a request as a `curl` command, so you can later send the same request from command line.